# iCloud key value lifecycle

Tags: ios, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

Given that iCloud key-value store entries are not deleted when the app that created them is uninstalled, when is the data deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual keys are removed when an app calls `-[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore removeObjectForKey:]`. That could include all data, or only part of it.

The data is *completely* removed when the user removes it, in the iCloud section of Settings (on iOS) or System Preferences (on Mac OS X, and yeah, even if it's an iOS-only app).